# Continuation or non-http traffic error

Tags: perl, apache2, cgi, wireshark

I am trying to send http file transfer (a video file) over the LAN network from apache2.2 running on Ubuntu.
The client becomes unresponsive after the file is served. The apache2 logs says response code 200 for the get request. 
When I looked in wireshark reports, I see lots of 'Continuation or non-http traffic'.
Not sure why I am getting this error, is there any way I can arrange the data packets or need to configure at network layer ? (proxy etc..) ?
Below is the server code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use File::Copy qw( copy );
use File::Spec::Functions qw( catfile );
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use Time::Local;
use HTTP::Status qw(:constants :is status_message);
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5 md5_hex md5_base64);
use File::Basename;
#use File::Slurp;
use URI;
use utf8;


my $extfile = '/home/suresh/clientrequest.txt';
open(FH, ">>$extfile") or die "Cannot open file";
my $query = CGI->new;
my $stcode = status_message(206);
my $uri =$ENV{'REQUEST_URI'};
my $rdate =strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z", localtime());
print FH "Client request: ", $ENV{'REQUEST_URI'}, "\n";
my $dir  = '/srv/samba/Assets';
my $nffFile = fileparse ("$uri", qr/\.[^.]*/);
my $fullFname = $nffFile . ".nff";
my $path = catfile($dir, $fullFname);
my $filesize = -s $path;
print FH "Size of the file: ", $filesize, "\n";
print FH "Requested File: ", $fullFname, "\n";
#Search requested asset files
opendir(DIR, $dir);
my @files = readdir(DIR);
if (grep($_=~/$fullFname/,@files)){
    print FH "Found the requested NFF file: ", $fullFname, "\n";

#    open my $fh, '<:raw', $path;
open (FILE, "< $path") or die "cannot open $fullFname\n";

print "$ENV{SERVER_PROTOCOL} 206 $stcode";
print("Content Type: application/octet-stream\n\n");


while (<FILE>) {

        print;
}
sleep(1);
close FILE or die "Cannot close the file";

}
```

Comment: Why are you sending a 206 response ("Partial Content") and then sending the entire file (without any of the required headers for 206)?

Comment: I wanted a simple standard http file transfer. The request headers from client says the bytes range as 188 so, I added 206 as only header. I tried with 200 but I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue. The issue was with realtek driver r8169 which was corrupted and causing packets drop by kernel and interface. I install 8168 which is latest driver and it solved the problem.